# Can we set our user profile picture in settings as a GIF?

Tags: gnome, gui, users, 22.04, system-settings

When going to "Users" in Settings, we have an option to set our user profile picture in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Is there any way we can set it up as a GIF?

Thanks.

Comment: so there'sno way....!!??? hmm

Comment: Note that this would require that whatever process displays the profile picture be capable of displaying animations. This isn't trivial and also takes up resources. I would be very surprised if this were actually possible.